# google maps navigation - dynamic points of interest

Tags: android, google-maps

Is it possible to implement some sort of dynamic points of interest for google maps on android?

The background is that I would like to use the original google maps navigation for android, but with points of interest which are polled from some webservice-backend, and displayed on along the route.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can store markers in webservice (php+mysql databse) and display it dynamicaly
Your questions answer is explained in below url with source code
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/storing-google-maps-android-api-v2-marker-locations-in-mysql/